# Vuejs 2 $refs returned undefined

Tags: html, vue.js

I am trying to reload the html5 audio when the page is loaded since it has a dynamic path but I can't seems to access the $ref property either on `mounted` or `watch` here is the code

```
<audio ref="player" controls>
                        <source v-bind:src="track">
                        Your browser does not support the audio element.
                    </audio>

watch:{
    details : function(){
        this.verdict = ''
        this.track = '../../public/wavfile/' + this.details.file;
        console.log(this.$refs)
    }
},
mounted(){
    console.log(this.$refs)
}
```

Comment: Maybe try using `nextTick` as explained at https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted to make sure the child components have been mounted as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref), you cannot access refs on initial render.

Comment: yah i just discovered it. Also the default settings of bootstrap modal has lazy loading and it affects the accessing of dom

Comment: this would be better if you explained it better for the reference of others. But I will accept it and thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
console.log(this.$refs['player'])
```

or

```
console.log(this.$refs.player)
```